# Switching between app and broswer ios

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

There is a scenario where tapping on link open's iOS native browser after which I need to close the browser and switch back to applicatio. Is there any possible way we can do the using Selenium commands.

Comment: Not sure about Selenium, but in general this can only be done in iOS9

Comment: Once you delegate the control over to Browser, you can't work with your app because it has gone to background state. If you are loading your own website, then you can use URL Scheme to open your app from web browser (but that will need to be triggered, it wont automatically take you back to your app). But in your specific case, it would be better to use UIWebView instead of native browser.

Comment: Also as mentioned before, iOS 9 shows a tiny back indicator in the status bar with the app's name if there is an app behind there. That is native functionality, something you have no control over anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using *sendkeys* method to tap at home button twice. Then try to tap at some place in the middle of the screen to get back to previously opened app. That could work, but I have not tried it.

Comment: Thanks Slavo , let me give a try on it.

Answer (score 0):

@vignesh    You can't switch between different apps in iOS. Currently, appium supports app switching between android apps only.

But you can run you app in background and after specified time it will be foreground.

Comment: suman , can you specify the selenium code type to make the app visible in foreground ?

Comment: @Vignesh , just call
    `driver.runAppInBackground(10);`

This will run the app in background for 10 seconds and will foreground automatically then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to move back from the browser.

driver.navigate().back();

Just try this out.